# ifdown em1 Users cannot control this device. Allow users to control em1 device

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, ethernet, sudo

**I want to allow users to control the em1 device in Linux:**

When I run this command:

```
ifdown em1
```

em1 is the embedded ethernet card 1, I want the user to be able to turn off the ethernet card.

On Fedora 17, I get this error message:

```
Users cannot control this device
```

I want a certain user to be able to run a certain command on Linux without giving rights to other users.  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1`:

```
USERCTL=yes
```

Then any user can run `ifup em1`/`ifdown em1`.

Comment: I added the `USERCTL="yes"` line (with quotes) and it worked for me.  That is a much better solution than using visudo.  +35 serotonin boost points for you.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use `sudo` to give the user on Fedora 17 the rights to control the em1 device:

**First verify that you infact cannot run `ifdown em1` as a user.**

```
el@defiant ~ $ /usr/sbin/ifdown em1

    Users cannot control this device.
```

**Login to a terminal as root**

```
su
<password>
```

**Install sudo if you don't already have it**

```
yum install sudo
```

**open up the `visudo` permissions editor**

Note, if you don't know how to use the `vi` editor, you'll either have to learn how or set the visudo path to editor as something else.

```
visudo
```

**this allows you to edit what users can do which commands as root on your system**

At the bottom of the file that is opened add these commands:

```
## Allows members of the users group to shutdown this system
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
%users  localhost=/usr/sbin/ifdown
```

**Save the visudo file, Get out of root, login as a user, and see if you can control em1**

```
el@defiant ~ $ /usr/sbin/ifdown em1
```